# Meteor auto refresh not working

Tags: meteor

My meteor local app simply stopped watching client files ("Client modified, refreshing"). It will still watch server files and trigger a "Server modified, restarting" and complete it, but ignores client changes.

Closing it (ctrl+c) and restarting it (meteor) doesn't fix it. Rebooting the PC doesn't fix it.

If I force a server refresh (changing server files by random), the next client file change will usually trigger a "client modified, refreshing" but will not complete it (hung forever).

I searched a lot and found thousand of people asking how to STOP files from being watched, but not questions about this problem =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching even more, I came across people suggesting 'downgrading' meteor to solve weird bugs (not exactly the one I'm facing). Still, 'downgrading' it to 1.4.1.3 (instead of the current 1.4.2.3) seemed to fix the problem, at least for now.

```
D:\somefolder> meteor --release 1.4.1.3
=> Using Meteor 1.4.1.3 as requested (overriding Meteor 1.4.2.3)
```

I don't think this really can be considered an answer, but at least the problem was 'solved'.

Comment: thanks for posting, i believe that the definition of answer which "solve the issue" :)

Comment: I've found a similar issue but with server code. It's absolutely random. When I modify some server code, the project does not refresh (ie: no _Meteor server restarted_ message). I'm on 1.4.4.2 meteor version. Instead of _downgrading_, I'll wait to upgrade to 1.5 and see if this issue disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, but resolved.

- Rename the proyect like MyApp.old
- Create a new proyect with meteor create MyApp (follow instruccion like run meteor npm install in meteor 1.4.3.2 version)
- Replace entire source code only and packages list from old version
- Run meteor